# How to perform with longadder

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, java-8, thread-safety

Hello I have an application calculate time and throwing an event according that. I would like to make my application with thread safe using longadder or whatever is suitable.

my class below;

```
    @Autowired
    EventListenerConfiguration eventListenerConfiguration;

    private volatile long lastReceivedMessage = System.currentTimeMillis();

 
    public void consume(String message) Integer partition,
                        (Headers.OFFSET) Long offset, Acknowledgment ack) {


        lastReceivedMessage = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {
            seervice.processMessage(message, ack, null);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${listenScheduled}", initialDelay = 100000)
    private void distanceBetweenLastReceivedMessageAndCurrentTime() {

        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastReceivedMessage;

        if (currentTime >= EventListenerConfiguration .getTotalMilliSecondTimeForError()) {

            EventUtil.publishEvent(THROW_ERROR_EVENT, EventSeverityStatus.ERROR, EventTypeStatus.CUSTOM, null);


        } else (currentTime >= EventListenerConfiguration.getTotalMilliSecondTimeForWarn()) {

            EventUtil.publishEvent(THROW_WARN_EVENT, EventSeverityStatus.WARN, EventTypeStatus.CUSTOM, null);

        }
}
```

so basicly how to convert my code without changing much to longAdder and also perform currentTime-lastReceiveMessage

Thank you

Comment: Hello @John deltana,
It looks like you are using a Spring Application to call your code. You mentioned that it's not acting in a thread-safe manner. It would be helpful to know what the observed behavior is. We may need a little more context before suggesting a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, I just want to prevent my events crushed its on timer I had to set with my yml I also tried volatile method if that helpful on that situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Evening. It appears that your issue is largely that `lastReceivedMessage` is a protected resource used by two threads. Whatever is running the **consume** method generates it, and then the Spring-Generated `@scheduled` thread consumes it.

Adding the **volatile** keyword will not prevent the code from reading the field. It will only prevent the code from caching the variable. (Read up on volatile https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/volatile-keyword-in-java/) If you want to treat the @Scheduled block as a critical region, and prevent the updating of the `lastRecievedMessage` until it is complete, I would recommend the following:

```
    private volatile long lastReceivedMessage = System.currentTimeMillis();
    private Semaphore resourceLock = new Semaphore(1);

    public void consume(String message) Integer partition,
    (Headers.OFFSET) Long offset, Acknowledgment ack) {

        resourceLock.acquireUninterruptibly();
        try {
            lastReceivedMessage = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } finally {
            resourceLock.release();
        }

        try {
            seervice.processMessage(message, ack, null);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${listenScheduled}", initialDelay = 100000)
    private void distanceBetweenLastReceivedMessageAndCurrentTime() {
        long currentTime = 0;

        resourceLock.acquireUninterruptibly();
        try {
                currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastReceivedMessage;
                
            if (currentTime >= EventListenerConfiguration .getTotalMilliSecondTimeForError()) {
                EventUtil.publishEvent(THROW_ERROR_EVENT, EventSeverityStatus.ERROR, EventTypeStatus.CUSTOM, null);

            } else (currentTime >= EventListenerConfiguration.getTotalMilliSecondTimeForWarn()) {
                EventUtil.publishEvent(THROW_WARN_EVENT, EventSeverityStatus.WARN, EventTypeStatus.CUSTOM, null);
            }
        } finally {
            resourceLock.release();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @John Deltana, if this is not the issue you are experiencing, then more clarity will need to be added to your question.

Comment: that is excatly what I wanted to that is very enlightening. Thank you so much